# Persitant backups in Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, backup

I have a system that is updated very often and I'm looking for a solution that would backup and log when file or number of files change on the server. I understand the amazing potential of git and svn but the usage here is different.

Users are uploading modified files to either an ftp or network drive.
DB entries are added and removed multiple times in the day.
System files are modified for testing or configuration.

Any assistance or recommendations would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enable VSS snapshots on the volume the data will be held.  VSS snapshots will take snapshots of a volume on a specified schedule.  You would be able to restore from a specific snapshot using the "previous Versions Tab" on the file/ folder. check out [What is Volume Shadow Copy Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757854%28WS.10%29.aspx) for more details.

This would backup the files at specified intervals but would not log when files are modified other than in their usual file attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar where I work using fossil. Set up a repository with the necessary files, then create a batch script with a couple commands in it.

```
change to your directory
fossil add "wild card to select files"
fossil commit -m "Automatic repo commit"
repeat as necesssary
```

Run this as a scheduled task on a short timer. Every time that fossil does an add, it will only add new files to the repository. The commit will then put every new file and edited file into your repository. If you want everything in the directory just use * for your wildcard.